# Streaming audio-in via WiFi

Tags: wireless-networking, audio-streaming

I've a DJ Setup in one room, and a PC which has an audio-in, now I want in the same WiFi network but another room stream that audio-in with as less latency as possible. I tried shoutcast already, but that has a latency of 10 seconds and more, what is really too much. The bandwidth should be absolutely enough for this operation, but I can't find any software which would allow me to stream that sounds into another room without a big latency.

Comment: How do you know the bandwidth is enough?

Comment: 100 mbit/s should be enough for some audio streaming, isn't it?

Comment: You're assuming you're getting 100 mbits/sec over wifi, while the actual throughput may be much lower depending on the signal. You may also want to take in to account the quality of the stream and the Mbps it's using. 10 seconds sounds high though. Have you tried VLC?

Comment: How can this be done via VLC? Currently the bandwidth is not the problem, more the software to use. How to setup the stream and how to access it on client, so there is as less latency as possible.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in vlc via subclient for a subsonic server.
It could also be done via:

- [Teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/windows.aspx) audio conferencing.
- [Tonido Desktop](http://www.tonido.com/tonidodesktop/)
- [Vibe Streamer](http://www.vibestreamer.com/)
- [Media Monkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com)
- [Media Portal](http://www.team-mediaportal.com/) or on linux [lmms](http://lmms.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

For those on a budget, there is a great kickstarter project with about 10 days left to go.
It's called ROCKI, and lets you upgrade any old audio hardware by plugging it in via an RCA line in socket (or the more expensive model has HDMI and optical).

A very cheap and easy solution to add some extra life to old audio hardware without having to replace everything.

[ROCKI Wifi Music System, From Every Phone, To All Speakers](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/rocki/rocki-wifi-music-system-from-every-phone-to-all-sp/)